# Perl match and extract phone number with (312) 555-1212 format

Tags: regex, perl

Trying to get perl to recognize and extract a phone number in a string with some odd formatting that is found in a file:

```
my $str = 'Phone:

(312) 555-1212 _
';
```

I tried but this solution but it winds up extracting all numbers from strings:

```
my @all_nums = $element =~ /(\d+)/g; 
  
 if (@all_nums) {
        
    my $ph = join('-', @all_nums);
    print "PHONE NO: $ph\n"; 
        
    push(@elements_found, $ph);
            
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps instead of a variable, you should show a text file as test case.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the output you get and output you expect.

Comment: Do you wish to extract the string `"(312) 555-1212"` or the three values `"312"`, `"555"` and `"1212"`, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a more precise regex for the number format:

```
my @all_nums = $element =~ /\((\d+)\) (\d+)-(\d+)/g; 
  
 if (@all_nums) {
        
    my $ph = join('-', $1, $2, $3);
    print "PHONE NO: $ph\n"; 
        
    push(@elements_found, $ph);
            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following demo code snippet reads line by line **DATA** block and extracts a phone if such exists in the line, otherwise skips to read next line. If phone number was found in the line then it printed on the screen.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4})/;

while( <DATA> ) {
    next unless /$re/;
    say "-- $1 --";
}

__DATA__
Phone:

(312) 555-1212 _

Call customer service at (328) 371-9302 for an assistance
```

Output

```
-- (312) 555-1212 --
-- (328) 371-9302 --
```

Following code sample reads **DATA** block into variable `$data` and then with assistance of *regular expression* extracts all phone numbers into array `@phones`, then prints them on the screen.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re = qr/(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4})/;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA>; };
my @phones = $data =~ /$re/g;

say for @phones;

__DATA__
Phone:

(312) 555-1212 _

Call customer service at (328) 371-9302 for an assistance
```

Output

```
(312) 555-1212
(328) 371-9302
```

Note: a task of validating a phone number is more complicated than demonstrated in these code samples